# Cannot apply texture when using THREE.Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a simple 2D triangle with 3 vertices and 1 face.

It works fine if use color in the material, but when I use texture I get `[.WebGLRenderingContext-0633E7D8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2`
The same material works fine for objects created with BoxGeometry.

```
        var wallTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("http://i.imgur.com/RiC9b5J.jpg");

        var wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: wallTexture});

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-100, 0, 0));
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 0));
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -150, 0));

        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
        geometry.computeFaceNormals();

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, wallMaterial);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pt9wnk4/8/

Comment: when you are creating geometry and you want it to be textured, you also need to create uv coordinates. The `.faceVertexUvs` attribute of the geometry must be populated.

Comment: @gaitat, thanks. Can you show how to do that? haven't found anything useful in the documentation.

Comment: this should help: http://jsfiddle.net/Immugio/Lg5vbzot/